# Understanding a step in a proof that $\int_a^bfd\gamma=\int_a^bf(t)\gamma'(t)dt$ for piecewise smooth $\gamma$ and continuous $f$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I am reading *Functions of one Complex Variable* by Conway and I am having trouble understanding the proof of this theorem

> **Theorem:** If $\gamma$ is piecewise smooth and $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, then
>
> $$\int_a^b f d \gamma = \int_a^b f(t) \gamma'(t) dt$$
>
> *Proof:* Again, we only consider the case where $\gamma$ is smooth. **Also, by looking at the real and imaginary parts of $\gamma$, we reduce the proof of the case where $\gamma([a, b]) \subset \mathbb{R}$.** Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta>0$ such that if $P =  \{ a=t_0< \ldots < t_n=b \}$ has $||P||< \delta$ then
>
> $$\left| \int_a^b f d \gamma - \sum_{k=1}^n f( \tau_k)[\gamma(t_k) - \gamma(t_{k-1})] \right| < \dfrac 12 \epsilon$$
>
> and
>
> $$\left| \int_a^b f(t) \gamma'(t) dt - \sum_{k=1}^n f( \tau_k)\gamma'(\tau_k)(t_k - t_{k-1})\right| < \dfrac 12 \epsilon$$
>
> for any choice of $\tau_k$ in $[t_{k-1}, t_k]$.
>
> [The proof keeps going on from here]

I'm not understanding the boldface part. The only thing I can think of is
$$\int_a^b f d \gamma = \int_a^b fd(\Re(\gamma) + i \Im (\gamma))$$

Then, if we equate this with the real part on the RHS, we would have to prove that

$$\int_a^b f d \Re (\gamma) = \int_a^b \Re(f \gamma')(t)$$

However, based on the sums involved, I don't think this is what's going on. Can anyone clarify this please? Thank you.

**Definition:** By the way, the definition Conway gives of $\int_a^b f d\gamma$ is:

If $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and $\gamma:[a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ then $\int_a^b f d\gamma$ is the complex number $I$ which satisfies: $\forall (\epsilon>0) \exists (\delta>0)$ such that for all partitions $P = {a = t_0< \ldots t_n = b}$ with $||P||< \delta$ we have

$$\left|I - \sum_{i=1}^n f( \tau_i )(\gamma(t_i) - \gamma (t_{i-1})) \right|<\epsilon$$

Comment: Proving $\int_a^b f\, d \Re (\gamma) = \int_a^b f\, \Re(\gamma')\, dt$ might be easier.

Comment: But doesn't it have to be $ \int_a^b , \Re( f\gamma')\, dt$ on the RHS? I don't think $ \Re( fg) = f \Re(g)$

Comment: That would make the value of the RHS real, but the value of the LHS can have a non-zero imaginary part.

Comment: Also in complex analysis you should take $\int_\gamma F(z)dz = \int_a^b F(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$ as the definition and just show it is independent of the choice of $C^1$ parametrization

Comment: Where is $\gamma([a,b])$ originally? The whole of $\mathbb C$? Or some domain or region?

Comment: @SeleneAuckland I don't see any restriction on it, it seems that it could be anywhere in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course  $\gamma (t)=\mathscr{R}(\gamma(t))+\mathscr{I}(\gamma (t))i$.

The trick here appears to be to consider the real and imaginary parts of $\gamma $ separately,  in order to simplify computations.